# How to JOIN [using Doctrine2 and CodeIgniter2]

Tags: php, class, join, doctrine

New to Doctrine, and trying to get a JOIN to work.

I've banged my head on this for awhile, and am slowly beginning to get the whole picture - its not as simply as I thought it would be.

I have two Entities with corresponding sql tables.  I'm attempting to run a query that will return data from both of them, linked.  A JOIN.

If I was doing this in straight SQL, it would look like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM mail_links a
    INNER JOIN mail_msgs b
    ON a.msg_id = b.id
```

I've tried a few things to make this work, including:

```
$query = $this -> doctrine -> em -> createQuery ("SELECT a FROM ORM\Dynasties2\Maillinks a JOIN ORM\Dynasties2\Mailmsgs b ON a.msgId = b.id");
```

That of course did not work.  I realized that this relies on having Entities created as Classes, or at least that's what some examples seemed to be doing.

And that's where I'm completely lost.

Is it correct that I need those entities to be Classes?  Are there any complete code examples of this (using CI) that would help me understand how to write the classes necessary for this JOIN?

Edit:

It just dawned on me that I *DO* have classes setup.  That's what my entities ARE.

So how do I make this work:

```
$query = $this -> doctrine -> em -> createQuery ("SELECT a FROM ORM\Dynasties2\Maillinks a JOIN ORM\Dynasties2\Mailmsgs b ON a.msgId = b.id");
```

It gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException' with message '[Semantical Error] line 0, col 70 near 'b ON a.msgId': Error: Identification Variable ORM\Dynasties2\Mailmsgs used in join path expression but was not defined before.' in /PATH/applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:47 Stack trace: #0 /PATH/applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(413): Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::semanticalError('line 0, col 70 ...') #1 /PATH/applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(914): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->semanticalError('Identification ...') #2 /PATH/applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php(1567): Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->JoinAssociationPathExpression() #3 /PATH/ in /PATH/applicationFolder/libraries/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 47

Comment: I'm not big into Doctrine but I found this article a while back. Make sure to read about the @JoinColumn http://wildlyinaccurate.com/integrating-doctrine-2-with-codeigniter-2/